# A weirdly difficult question on probability of flipping a coin.

Tags: probability, algorithms, education

### **The Question:**

Assume the coin is perfectly fair, and that it cannot land on its side. Now let's imagine I throw the coin T times, it lands on the same side, X times in a row in T throws, what is the probability (P) this happens N times?

### **The question with numbers**

Let's say I throw a coin 200 (T) times, what is the probability (P) it lands exactly 7 (X) times in a row on the same face, twice (N)?

### **To Note**

1. The coin has to land exactly X times in a row, if it lands less or more it does not count. This means if I do 7 heads in a row at the start, the flip after must be tails, if I do it in the middle the flip before and after must be tails and if I do it at the end the flip before has to be tails.
2. If I land seven heads in a row and seven tails in a row then N is 2.
3. I found this question out myself, I have no idea how hard it is or if someone has already done it, I study math in high school but I have not been able to find a solution to my own question. If you find a solution can you show the steps as well as the reasoning behind it.
4. Sorry if it is difficult to understand or there are mistakes in my English but it is not my first language.